# Basic Python: How do I normalize a data series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 5 columns indexed by date.  I would like to normalize these data series by the first item in their lists.

```
                A   B   C   D   E
    1/1/2017    3   4   1   2   3
    1/2/2017    7   4   4   3   3
    1/3/2017    2   5   5   4   3
    1/4/2017    2   5   3   6   3
    1/5/2017    2   2   2   6   6
```

for example, in column A, i would like to divided everything by 3, the first item on the list.  Same for column B to E.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you done anything so far?

Comment: What's a dataframe? I don't think just basic Python has that.

Comment: df = df/df.index[1]...don't think this works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [100]: df.div(df.iloc[0])
Out[100]:
                 A     B    C    D    E
1/1/2017  1.000000  1.00  1.0  1.0  1.0
1/2/2017  2.333333  1.00  4.0  1.5  1.0
1/3/2017  0.666667  1.25  5.0  2.0  1.0
1/4/2017  0.666667  1.25  3.0  3.0  1.0
1/5/2017  0.666667  0.50  2.0  3.0  2.0
```

or

```
In [101]: df / df.iloc[0]
Out[101]:
                 A     B    C    D    E
1/1/2017  1.000000  1.00  1.0  1.0  1.0
1/2/2017  2.333333  1.00  4.0  1.5  1.0
1/3/2017  0.666667  1.25  5.0  2.0  1.0
1/4/2017  0.666667  1.25  3.0  3.0  1.0
1/5/2017  0.666667  0.50  2.0  3.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `div`

```
df.div(df.iloc[0,:],1)
Out[496]: 
                 A     B    C    D    E
1/1/2017  1.000000  1.00  1.0  1.0  1.0
1/2/2017  2.333333  1.00  4.0  1.5  1.0
1/3/2017  0.666667  1.25  5.0  2.0  1.0
1/4/2017  0.666667  1.25  3.0  3.0  1.0
1/5/2017  0.666667  0.50  2.0  3.0  2.0
```